# Can't get Bonjour working in home network

Tags: router, dlna, bonjour

I've expanded my home network. Now I have a WAG120N DSL router and TL-WR841N router.

WAG120N is "master" (connected to internet and DHCP server for TL) while TL is used for the rest of the clients.

Everything works great but Bonjour not. I can reach computers using IP but I would like to get Bonjour working.

Comment: Which devices use Bonjour for which service?

Comment: Well, I have Synology NAS and couple of Macbooks. I cannot see any of these

Answer (score 0):

Something to try: I have solved vexing problems I have had with iTunes home sharing by doing a repair install on Bonjour.